# URL for opening Interactive Report Layout not working

Tags: oracle-apex

The url to an IR report url is not working when using the link example prvided by page designer.
The example in the page designer shows like `f?p=&APP_ID.:59:&APP_SESSION.:IR[HS]_34718`
When using in on a public page without session id, the report will not open. No error shown just a blank page.

i try using the old style for the url `http://server_ip:8080/ords/f?p=41905101:59::IR_34718` 
=>works flawless

[Page Designer URL Suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGFrA.jpg)
APEX Version 5.1.4

Comment: I tried with a report on the EMP table. Static id of the interactive report is EMP_IR2. Url is ```https://myserver/pls/apex/f?p=12345:30:113306489867725::NO:RP:IR[EMP_IR2]C_ENAME:KING``` and it works just fine. Could it be your syntax is not correct ? In the old syntax the REQUEST value of the url contained the static id of the report. In the new syntax that is no longer the case. In your url you have put the "IR[HS]_34718" in the place of the request.

Comment: What APEX version are you working with?

Comment: I added APEX Version and the URL Suggestion copied from the Page Designer Saved Report Link example

Comment: @KoenLostrie. Providing a Filter in the URL works great:

Comment: @KoenLostrie. Providing a Filter in the URL works great
[link]http://serverip:8080/ords/f?p=41905101:59:::::IRC_HALLE:H3a
As soon as i add the Report Static ID the url does not work:
[link] http://serverip:8080/ords/f?p=41905101:59:::::IR[HALLENSTATUS]C_HALLE:H3a

Comment: Misunderstood the original question - I tried using the request syntax on 19.1 and it works fine for me. It opens the saved report as expected. Unfortunately I don't have a 5.1 instance to test on. The url I used was 
```https://myserver/pls/apex/f?p=12345:30:9367639950297:IR[EMP_IR3]_142887842:NO:RP::```